# twisted modification of the code does not work

Tags: python, twisted

The twisted -y command runs the.tac file, and the code modification does not take effect。

this is service.tac file code

`from config import config`

this is config.py file code

```
class Config:
     def __init__(self):
          print "files: 1111"
config = Config()
```

I started it with the twisted -y service.tac command,The first time I executed print files: 1111.
I changed files: 1111 to files: 2222,Run twisted -y service.tac command again,The output is files: 1111.

Can anyone help me with this question

Comment: Looks like that's because the module was already loaded, so was not reloaded. That's how Python normally works. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26008037/3004881 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2026091/3004881

Comment: But nothing happened when I restarted the system

Comment: Well, then maybe you're leaving something out from your description of what you did. Maybe you have different copies of config.py on your system, maybe you "installed" the older version somewhere, and twistd is using that version?

Comment: The problem has been solved with the rebuild method，Thank you very much